# iPhone - Iterating through Array of dictionaries and getting an object

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

In my application, I'm having NSArray that holds objects of NSDictionary.
In each dictionary, there's one "Primary" that holds value of type NSNumber which stores "YES" or "NO" (boolean value). And only dictionary object in the array can have the value "YES".
Without using loops how can I get the dictionary object where the "Primary" key is YES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a convenience method on `NSArray` to find the object, but be aware, that such a method still uses a loop internally to find the object.

```
NSUInteger indexOfPrimary = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"Primary"] boolValue];
}];
NSDictionary *primary = nil;
if (indexOfPrimary != NSNotFound) {
    primary = [array objectAtIndex:indexOfPrimary];
}
```

Another option would be `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`.

Comment: Can you explain me little bit about the code that you wrote? (Dont' mind i'm new to iphone coding)

Comment: Not unless you tell me what exactly you do and don't understand.

Comment: I'm an iPhone developer. But I never came across some code like "(^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)". I didn't understand this part.

Comment: This is Block Notation, added in iOS 4.2 (or was it 4.1?).  blocks are a way to treat a block of code like an object.  Read Apples developer documents on using Blocks and you'll get the idea.

Comment: Blocks were introduced in iOS 4.0 (and before in OS X 10.6).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "without using loops"?   Meaning *you* don't write a for loop, or do you mean in that any routine you use would not use a loop?  If you want the answer in "constant time", not "linear time", you should just keep a pointer to the record.   If you don't own the insertion / deletion of elements into the array, then no, there's no way other than a linear time look-up, either doing a loop yourself, or using NSArray's

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```